# Scheme, how to square just negative numbers in a list leaving the rest of the list intact

Tags: list, scheme, mit-scheme, accumulate

I have been working on a call to accumulate which goes as follows:

```
(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      initial
      (op (car sequence)
          (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))
```

However when I try to square something by slecting it through filter the answer doesn't work. What I have so far is this:

```
(define (f2b items)
   (accumulate (lambda (x y)
     (cons (append 
        (map square (filter negative? (filter number? x))) x) y)) () items)
  )
```

The Input I give is:

```
(f2a '(("sdas" 89) (-53 "sad")))
```

The output I get is:

```
 ((sdas 89) (2809 -53 sad))
```

I can't seem to get the negative number to go away.

Comment: What's your *input*? It looks like you have a nested list of two lists, but your code doesn't handle that.

Comment: @GregHewgill I put the input that I am giving.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to use filter and map. Filter is predefined but it looks like this.

```
   (define (filter1 predicate sequence)
          (cond 
               ((null? sequence) null)
                ((predicate (car sequence))
                 (cons (car sequence)
                       (filter predicate (cdr sequence))))
                (else (filter predicate (cdr sequence)))))
```

map is also predefined, it just runs a function over a list.

This should be pretty simple to write, but incase you need help you should just write a lamdba for the predicate in filter.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the functionality you describe is not usually the job of an accumulator. Instead, squaring negative numbers in a list seems like the perfect job for something like a map.

First, let's do:

```
(define (make-positive x)
    (if (and (number? x) (negative? x))
        (square x)
        x))
```

Now suppose we want to operate on a list called `lst`. If it was just a flat list, like `'(1 "2" -5 -4 6)`, then we could just

```
(map make-positive lst)
```

Since we need to operate on lists which are nested two levels deep, we could do:

```
(map (lambda (x)
        (map make-positive x))
     lst)
```

If we wanted to operate on lists which are nested arbitrarily deep, we could do:

```
(define (nested-map fn elm)
   (if (list? elm)
       (map (lambda (x) (nested-map fn x)) elm)
       (fn elm)))

(nested-map make-positive lst)
```

PS - we can define `map` like this:

```
(define (map fn lst)
   (if (empty? lst)
       '()
       (cons (fn (car lst))
             (map fn (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why I didn't think to use map, however, this makes perfect sense!